# Inno Setup Creates Registry Key But Not shown in MsConfig

Tags: registry, inno-setup, autostart

With this line of code in Inno Setup I create a autostart registry key for my application.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Iris_Request_Application"; ValueData: """{app}\startup\center_approver_client_traybar_service.exe"""; Flags: deletekey uninsdeletekey
```

When I look into regedit the registry key is visible. But when I look into msconfig there is no according auto start entry.

Does anyone know why this happen?

I have already tested if it's a problem with the permissions of the installer. But also

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

changes nothing.

Comment: It works for me with exactly same InnoSetup code.

Comment: Questions 1) Does the application start on login (even if not shown in msconfig)? 2) Does the application even exist? 3) It can be a problem with the application executable itself [msconfig having some problems with it]. Try to replace the executable for a test. I've tested this with `MyProg.exe` that comes with InnoSetup (I have renamed it to `center_approver_client_traybar_service.exe`)

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help Martin. After your comment I have tried it with the     MyProg.exe and it worked. It looks like that also the traybar service registry entry was created correctly. But because in my traybar the logo of a old version of the traybar service appeared I had thought that there was a problem with creating a new registry entry. It seams that Inno Setup do not replace some old program files with the newer ones.